# What is Laravel Sanctum supposed to be able to do?

Tags: laravel

To be honest, I don't understand the concept of Laravel Sanctum. Before there was Sanctum, people used JWT. That always worked very well. In other frameworks in the Node context, I only use JWT. I am very confused by the paragraph about the SPA Auth (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#how-it-works-spa-authentication). It talks about Sanactum also using the web auth. Does that mean that if I log in via the web route (`auth`), I can also use the api route (`auth:sanctum`)?

Thanks! Max

Comment: Sanctums SPA authentication uses the session like normal Laravel authentication. You'd prefer that if JWT is overkill for your use case. `auth:sanctum` is for Sanctum's token authentication which is different to SPA authentication

Comment: @apokryfos Merci for comment:-)! Ok. Let me summarise. Laravel sets me a session cookie when I log in via the web auth and I can include the XSRF token in blade in my header. Now when I fire off an xhr request against my Laravel api, what do I need to include in the header? Then XSRF token or the session token?

Comment: @apokryfos Presumably this is not possible. So I have to put all protected API calls into my web route and protect them with the web 'auth'. But then it feels unclean and kind of hacky.

Comment: If it's on the same domain the browser will send the session cookie automatically. You might need to send the CSRF token (either as a `_token` field in the post request or as an the XSRF cookie or header, XSRF is encrypted though so can't be used in `_token`)

Comment: @apokryfos Ok. Thank you for your answer. Can you please share an xhr request example header here? You are welcome to do it as an answer, which I would then value accordingly :-)